# Scheduling non-periodic events with multiple threads

Tags: python

I am attempting to develop a GUI program in python (using pyqt5) to interact with a data acquisition device (DAQ) that will be connected via LAN or USB to a windows PC. On the click of a button (in the GUI), the DAQ will perform a test.

Each "Test" will consist of collecting a reading (collecting a reading takes about 1.5 seconds) at user-defined intervals from the start of the test (e.g., 0.1 min, 0.2 min, 0.5 min, 1 min, 2 min, 5 min...1000 min etc.). A reading is collected by execution of a function, so code for a single test might look like this:

```
import time

t=[0,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000] #times from start of test to collect readings at (min)
intervals=[t[i]-t[i-1] for i in range(1,len(t))] #time delta between readings (min)

def GetReading():
     #some code to connect to the DAQ (using pyvisa) and collect reading
     reading=['2020-01-02 17:33:33',1.23456] #the data returned from the DAQ
     return reading

def RunTest(r):
     results=[GetReading()] #get the initial (t=0) reading 
     ReadTime=1.5 #time in seconds to collect 1 reading (I may use an implementation of
                  #time.run_process() or similar to actually calculate this this instead)
     for j in r:
          time.sleep(j*60-ReadTime)
          results.append(GetReading())
     return results

RunTest(intervals)
```

The DAQ can only perform one reading at a time. I would like to be able to run multiple tests simultaneously, and have my program automatically wait and start a new test when it is feasible (i.e., delay starting a test on click if another test is already running).

The first, say 5 readings, are imperative that they happen on time, but the subsequent readings of a given test can be delayed by a bit without affecting the quality of the test. For example, if a test is running at the 0.2 min reading interval, and the user initiates a new test, the program would wait until the current test completed say, the 5 min reading, before starting the additional test sequence.

Subsequent readings beyond the 5 min reading could be delayed to collect the first 5 readings of a new test sequence, or collect a reading from another test.

I'm struggling with how to program this, conceptually. I think i need to use multiprocesses or similar to allow multiple tests to be run in parallel (though no actual parallel readings can occur). Or, perhaps I can use scheduler? I'm just not sure how to implement either of these; I've never used them before, and I'm having trouble understanding examples I find in the context of my problem.

Furthermore, I need to be able to access results (output from RunTest) between calls to GetReading() (e.g., to view data as the test progresses), and using the time.sleep wouldn't allow that.

**UPDATE**

The measurement the DAQ is collecting is deformation, via a LVDT. 
The time zero in var `t` is not actually the button click supplied by the user. On button click, the DAQ will open the specified channel and the program will monitor for a change in deformation above a certain threshold. The user will then physically start the test (which involves adding a weight on some material, to measure stress-strain properties), and time zero will occur at `i-1` where `i` is the first instance of change above the threshold is detected (i.e., `t=0` corresponds to the zero-deformation reading the instant before the weight is added). I need the whole process from button click, to adding the weight, to collecting up to the 5 minute reading to be uninterrupted for a single test (Deformation occurs most rapidly, and potentially erratically, in the first 5 minutes or so).

Comment: could you please specify in more detail.

How do you want to start multiple tests?

How many tests do you want to start per minute?

You want to start them as fast as possible or do  you want to start them whenever you click on a GUI window?

If you want to start them as fast as possible, then you had to find an algorithm, which tries to pack the tests as sclose as possible with keeping your constraint being that the first 5 measurements should be nicely spaced.

Comment: In order to do correct scheduling it's also important to know the max time a measurement would need and not the average time. Would that also be 1.5 seconds?

Comment: To answer the questions, multiple tests would be started with multiple button clicks in the GUI (user would set up reading intervals, and then click button to start one test). A test would begin ASAP, after button click, provided a currently running test doesn't have an early measurement scheduled. No more than 3 tests would be run at any given time (current limitation of our sensors), and i can't foresee a situation where more than one test could physically be started within a minute or two.

Comment: So it would be OK to start new tests only after all active tests finished their early measurements?

Will the user setup intervals (like in var `intervals`) or would he setup absolute times (as in var `t`)

If I write an example code. shall I base it on tables like `t` or on tables like `interval`

What would be the definition for early measurements? (interval < 1 minute)

Comment: Yes, it would be OK to start new tests only after all active tests finished their early measurements. The way I would handle that would be a message box that tells the user that the test will start in x minutes. The user will define absolute times (as in var `t`). Early measurements would be `t<=5` minutes. I updated the original post with some additional information on var `t`. Sorry, I am trying to keep the scope of the question as narrow as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works, but doesn't ensure, that first measurements of a new test are prioritized.

If this is is essential, then the solution will be a little bit more difficult.

In order to be sure, that only one function / thread is reading data at a given time, you can use a mutex (threading.Lock)

```
from threading import Lock

read_lock = Lock()


def get_data():
     with read_lock:
         #some code to connect to the DAQ (using pyvisa) and collect reading
         reading=['2020-01-02 17:33:33',1.23456] #the data returned from the DAQ
         return reading
```

I'd propose to write a function, that fetches the result and appends it to a results list.

Any object being modified by one thread and read by another should be protected with a Lock, therefore there is a second lock to avoid simultaneous reading / writing of results.

```
results_lock = Lock()
def get_and_store_data(results):
    result = get_data()
    with results_lock:
        results.append(result)
```

You can schedule a get_and_store_data action with threading.Timer

Below a the full code example:

```
from threading import Lock
from threading import Timer


t=[0,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000] #times from start of test to collect readings at (min)

read_lock = Lock()
results_lock = Lock()

def get_data():
    import time
    import datetime
    import random
    with read_lock:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        #some code to connect to the DAQ (using pyvisa) and collect reading
        reading = [
            datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            random.randint(0,10000) / 1000,
            ]
    return reading

def get_and_store_data(results):
    result = get_data()
    with results_lock:
        results.append(result)

# schedule measures for one test
def schedule_measures(measure_times, results):
    timers = []
    for t in measure_times:
        timer = Timer(t, get_and_store_data, args=[results])
        timer.start()
        timers.append(timer)

def main():
    results = []
    meas_times = [tim * 1 for tim in t]
    schedule_measures(meas_times, results)
    while True:
        msg = "Please press enter to display results or q and enter to quit"
        choice = input(msg).strip()
        if choice == "q":
            break
        print("Results:")
        with results_lock:
            for result in results:
                print(result)

main()
```

If you want to reduce the 'drift' between measurements, then you could do something like:

```
import time

def schedule_measures(measure_times, results):
    timers = []
    t_0 = time.time()
    for t in measure_times:
        now = time.time()
        timer = Timer(t - (now - t_0), get_and_store_data, args=[results])
        timer.start()
        timers.append(timer)
```

Though the drift will probably be low enough anyways, but it's a neat trick if you have more CPU intensive actions in your schedule function or if you do not want to schedule all events at startup.

For prioritizing measurements it might perhaps be easier to create a sorted list of lists with the calculated times when the measurement should be performed and start the next timer only when the previous timer fired. there had to be some logic to decide which measurement should be the next one to be scheduled. I don't have time now, but will probably come back within the next 12 hours with a suggested algorithm

Comment: Thank you, I'm digesting your suggestions. A couple initial questions: when I run the code, I get hung up after cancelling the operation (q + enter), presumably on the "break" command, any idea why? Also, the meas_times in main() should be [tim*60 for tim in t], since threading.Timer takes seconds, correct? Ultimately, I will need to figure a way to prioritize initial measurements of a test when a new instance of get_and_store_data() is started.

Comment: Also, the modified schedule_measures is slick, since I don't know for sure how long each measurement will take, and may be variable.

Comment: timer threads are no daemon threads by default, which means, that as soon as you quit the main applications, the threads will probably be termianted as well.
You will have a QT application that will probably be open during the run of the whole test.

If this is not the cvase, then we had to declaret the timers threads as daemon threads. I can show you how to do it if necessary